# SQl sorting based on certain property value of joined table

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I've the following tables with some data:

```
Collector:
dcid  name   hostid userid
123   test   host1  234
567   hello  host2  345

CollectorConfiguration:
ID   propertyname  propertyvalue  collector_id(foreign key)
id1  c_source      local          123
id2  c_createdby   admin          123
id3  c_pattern     JBoss          123
id4  c_source      remote         567
id4  c_createdby   admin          567
id4  c_pattern     Apache         567
```

Now I need to get all records from Collector table with sorting on column value "c_pattern" in CollectorConfiguration table.

I tried writing query using inner join but I couldn't get the desired result. Please help.

Note: The returned result contain only the Columns of Collector table,i.e, it should behave like select * from Collector  but with sortinn on c_pattern property value.

```
Desired output(with ascending order on c_pattern):
567  hello host2 345
123  test  host1 234
```

Comment: You should provide your desire output. Also show us what have you tryed.

Comment: what mean sort on `propety name "c_pattern" ` ??  You sort on a column not in a value of that column, unless you mean filter by that value.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've edited the question accordingly. Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Yes, You ask for order but i dont see any order there. Looks like you are asking for just choose one `collector_id`, dont see you use `propertyname`

Comment: If you see the ColectorConfiguration table , for colelctor(123), c_pattern value is JBoss and for colelctor(567), c_pattern value is Apache.  So sorting should be done c_pattern value.

Comment: Outer joins LEFT/RIGHT will give you desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the EAV model you should have a bunch of helper views to overcome the problems like this. The views will act as tables, such as collector_patterns, collector_sources, etc.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Collector c LEFT JOIN
CollectorConfiguration cc on c.dcid = cc.collector_id
where cc.propertyname = 'c_pattern'
ORDER BY cc.propertyvalue DESC
```

So, to make a view from this query you would write it like this:

```
CREATE VIEW collector_pattern AS
SELECT c.*, cc.propertyvalue AS pattern
FROM Collector c LEFT JOIN
CollectorConfiguration cc on c.dcid = cc.collector_id
where cc.propertyname = 'c_pattern'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* FROM Collector a
LEFT JOIN CollectorConfiguration b ON b.collector_id=a.dcid
WHERE b.propertyname="c_pattern"
```

Rather the question is not so clear to me, but I guess you are looking for so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer almost worked, only I need to add order by clause to your query.

Answer (score 1):

Still not clear on the pattern, but should look like this

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0de52/3)

```
SELECT c.[dcid], c.[name], [hostid], [userid]
FROM Collector c
LEFT JOIN CollectorConfiguration cc 
    ON cc.collector_id=c.dcid
WHERE cc.propertyname = 'c_pattern'
```

Comment: Your answer almost worked only I need to mention order by  in the query and thank you very much for taking time on this.